# Optimized solution for checking whether two-time interval arrays are overlapping or not?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures, time, intervals

Can you find whether two-time interval arrays are overlapping or not, in an optimized way?
Suppose input array A contains 10 elements, and each and every element have a start date and end date, And similarly,  input array B contains 4 elements, and each and every element have a start data and end data. Now find whether A and B are overlapping or not?

**Example 1:**

***Input:***

```
A={[1,5],[7,10],[11,15]}; //Array A contains 3elements, and each element have start and end time.
B={[6,10],[1,5]};//Array B contains 2elements, and each element have start and end time.
```

***Output:*** Yes // why because A and B are overlapping at [6,10] || [1,5]

**Example 2:**

***Input*:**

```
A={[1,5],[8,10],[11,15]}; //Array A contains 3elements, and each element have start and end time.
B={[5,8],[15,16]};//Array B contains 2elements, and each element have start and end time.
```

***Output:*** No // why because A and B are not-overlapping at [5,8] || [15,16]

I know we can solve this problem by using brute force, by iterating each element
in B and comparing with each element of A to check whether overlapping or not(A[i].start<=B[j].start and A[i].end>B[j].start), it'll take O(N*M) where N is length of array A and M is length of B.

Can you please optimize the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the array according to the start times. You can then check if the end time of an element is greater than the start time of next element by iterating through both the arrays simultaneously(use two pointers). If it is the case, then you have found an overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do

1. Build a **segment tree** using the values of array A. if the first interval id (l1, r1), 2nd is (l2, r2) and so on.
2. for every interval in A(li, ri) update the segment tree such that we update each element in the interval (li, ri) to 1. this can be done in O(logn) using **lazy propagation**
3. now for each interval in B(lj, rj) try to query the segment tree for this range. a query would return the sum of the range (lj, rj)
4. if sum is 0, then that range is non overlapping. else it is overlapping

overall complexity **O(nlogn)**

Comment: While this works, segment trees are a bit of an overkill for this problem. When working with simple sums on segments, if the data does not change over time (we only ask questions and don't add or remove segments), segment trees can be replaced by precomputed prefix sums: sums on intervals [0, X] for every X. After that, sum on [A, B] is just sum on [0, B] minus sum on [0, A-1]. After initializing (sorting the input may be necessary), these are faster in use, O(1) instead of O(log n), and do the same job.

Comment: The mentioned "precomputed prefix sums" approach is, in essence, conceptually similar to the other answer by @yashmahajan.